# Removing char from string?

Tags: java, string, replace

I am searching for the following text in an input string: `+Bob`

If the program finds `+Bob`, I want it to remove the `+` before Bob

However, I do not want the program to eliminate all `+`'s, just `+`'s **before or after** Bob, with or without intervening whitespace. So a string for example of: `+ Bob` still counts as `+Bob`.

Comment: does that mean you want to remove the `+` anytime it falls before `bob` such as if there were 10 spaces between `+` and `bob` or are you just taking into account the single space?

Comment: the first thing that you said

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish here? With all the changes to the question I'm starting to wonder whether you're going about this the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String str = "+Bob foo + bar";
str = str.replace("+Bob", "Bob");
System.out.println(str);
```

> Bob foo + bar

To handle a space between `+` and `Bob` you can use regular expressions:

```
String str = "+Bob foo + bar";
str = str.replaceAll("\\+\\s*Bob", "Bob");
```

To check for a plus afterwards, use

```
str = str.replaceAll("Bob\\s*\\+", "Bob");
```

Comment: LOL Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of that ... I was finding indexes and sh*t, LOL

Comment: How would I modify that to replace the + if it was at the end of Bob (ex: Bob+)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String regexp = "(?)\\+(\\s?)+Bob";
    System.out.println("+Bob foo + bar".replaceAll(regexp, "Bob"));
    System.out.println("+  Bob foo + bar".replaceAll(regexp, "Bob"));
    System.out.println("+  Bob foo + bar  +Bob".replaceAll(regexp, "Bob"));
    System.out.println("+  Bob foo + bar  +    Bob".replaceAll(regexp, "Bob"));
 }
}
/* output :
Bob foo + bar
Bob foo + bar
Bob foo + bar  Bob
Bob foo + bar  Bob
*/
```

Comment: How could I modify your code to work for ~Bob and -Bob and *Bob etc?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I downvoted you guys because the answer is: use StringBuffer.deleteCharAt(int Index)